# protect/unprotect range if a specific cell has changed to a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to make a specific range not changeable. but if a specific cell has changed from "no" to "yes" then the range should be changeable. and if the specific cell changed from "yes" to "no" then the range should be not changeable again.

How could I realize that in googe app script?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use the relevant Apps Script trigger for your usage environment, and the relevant Spreadsheet Service methods.

Comment: i use onEdit and if column to trigger that is no problem. But the rest is a big problem for me. please help a bit more specific. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should get you started. Basically, protecting stuff in Apps Script is easy; Removing the protection is more tedious. Because of that, I'd recommend adding a description to the protected range in question (as I've done with "Test1"), after which, the below loop would find and remove it with ease.

I've attached it to [this demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TfKrDMj3Tsx3Zq8SKo0vxWzpldvsubf58U2OO_7JG7A/edit?usp=sharing) so you have context with the data I was working with.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // 0 == first sheet.
  var ee = event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  if (ee == "A2") { // Check if edited cell is the one we're watching.
    if (event.value == "yes"){ // If the value == "yes", do stuff.
      var protections = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'Test1') { // If protection description == "Test1"...
          protections[i].remove(); // then remove protection.
        }
      }
    } 
  }  
}

function setProtected(){
  // Sets the desired range to protected with "Test1" description for demonstration.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var protectedRows = sh.getRange("C2:C11");
  protectedRows.protect().setDescription("Test1");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was very helpful. 
One Question: what happens if i insert a row before A2? moves then the protected range automatically one row down? or must i update the range manually?

Comment: @PascalL I suspect the protected range would shift just like a formula does, but I'm not at a computer to test it at the moment.